# upower in docker is getting me strange errors when starting

Tags: docker, freebsd, alpine-linux, battery

i have the following docker file

```
FROM alpine:latest

#add curl for better handling
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
RUN apk add linux-headers 
# Update & Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
    git \
    bash \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    bzip2-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    sqlite-dev \
    build-base \
    upower
```

in which i'm asking for upower.
When i launch the daemon from inside the docker i'm getting

```
bash-5.1# ./usr/lib/upower/upowerd

(upowerd:159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:20:47.487: g_dbus_proxy_get_connection: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(upowerd:159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:20:47.487: g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(upowerd:159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:20:47.487: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(upowerd:159): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: 13:20:47.487: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: Unknown reason

(upowerd:159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:20:47.488: g_dbus_proxy_get_connection: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(upowerd:159): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:20:47.488: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

which is ofc bad since i cant get battery related information.
Can anyone help me out to understand what (a package maybe) i'm missing?

Comment: Docker is generally an isolation system, and containers can't usually access the host's hardware devices.  You might be better running this program directly on the host.

Comment: I guess so, even though im quite sure it is possible to call host executables from within a docker. Still i might be better off using a python script directly on the host as you said